# Python (if, else, elif)

Tags: python-2.7

I have a problem it only show 
  Louis (650 Perm) and when you click again it will show Louis (In use) but the 3rd time it's  Louis (650 Perm) again and I can't find the problem

```
def example():
    if louis_inventory and louis == 0:
         pointstore_skin_ct.addline('->1. Louis (650) Perm')
    elif louis_inventory == 1 and louis == 0:
        pointstore_skin_ct.addline('->1. Louis (In use)')
    elif louis_inventory and louis == 1:
        pointstore_skin_ct.addline('->1. Louis (Not in use)')
```

Comment: Fix your indenting if it's not actually like that

Comment: The indenting is not the problem sir.

Comment: Yes it is. The code you pasted raises an IndentationError.

Comment: need a `:` after `example()` too

Comment: Well because I don't know how to post questions here, this is my first question

Comment: @YehudaMunkzino, the reason people are criticizing your code is that it's hard to fix code when it has errors besides the one you're asking about.  If you're getting errors other than the ones people are pointing out, then obviously your real code differs from what you posted.  In which case, what use will people's answers be to you?

Comment: Also, what are the values of `louis_inventory` and `louis`?  We don't know what "when you click again" means, so it's hard to tell what result we should expect from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if louis_inventory and louis == 0:
```

This will catch every cases where `louis_inventory` is truthy - e.g. anything nonzero in case of an int - and `louis` is zero.

So the first `elif` case is unreachable. I have no idea what exactly you are trying to do but this might fix it:

```
def example():
    if louis_inventory == 1 and louis == 0:
        pointstore_skin_ct.addline('->1. Louis (In use)')
    elif louis_inventory and louis == 0:
        pointstore_skin_ct.addline('->1. Louis (650) Perm')
    elif louis_inventory and louis == 1:
        pointstore_skin_ct.addline('->1. Louis (Not in use)')
```

It will jump into the first block if the value is exactly 1 and in the second one if it's any other non-zero value.

Comment: `elif louis_inventory and louis == 0:
        pointstore_skin_ct.addline('->1. Louis (650) Perm')` it doesn't read it, i know sounds weird but the line is invsible